# Multiple queue trigger web jobs based on functionality vs single web job

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have an Azure App Service where multiple web jobs. These web jobs are queue triggered (there is a storage account where I have multiple queues created for different code functionality and each web job gets triggered when a message is added to the queue it is listening to).

For example:

- insert queue messages -> handled by insert web job
- update queue messages -> handled by update web job
- delete queue messages -> handled by delete web job

All web jobs are hosted in the same App Service.

From resource consumption (CPU, memory usage) point of view which approach is better:

1. Have dedicated queues and web jobs based on functionality?
2. Have a "master" queue and a single web job that listens to the queue and perform different operations based on message type?

Comment: "Performance" is a bit too broad, because there are likely tradeoffs. Can you be more specific, e.g. optimizing for scalability, or latency, or resource usage, or something else...

Comment: Yes, I meant resource usage: memory/CPU